# Measure how long program runs

Tags: c#, timer

I'd like to create a timer for my C# project. My thought of how I would do this is simply to get the local time att the start of the program and save it to a variable. Then when the program is done or closed, the program would check for the current time again and save it to another variable. Then take the new time subtracted with the first time and save it to a third variable. Then it would show up the variable and show the time you've been in the program in seconds.

Comment: Side note: avoid new here/thank you notes in your posts. Also "timer" in C#/programming is usually entity that fires events based on time passed, I think you want to "measure time" (I've changed title, feel free to edit/revert if it does not match your intentions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accurately compute time you can use the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// ... time goes by
var elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

The variable `elapsed` contains a `TimeSpan` with the time elapsed between the two calls. This timer is highly accurate. If millisecond precision does not matter you can simply subtract two `DateTime` values instead:

```
var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
// ... time goes by
var end = DateTime.UtcNow;
var elapsed = end - start;
```

Using UTC performs better and you do not have to take daylight savings into consideration.

Comment: Okay. Could you explain how I use that class?

Comment: 1: Use google "stopwatch class" or follow the link. 2: read documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a Stopwatch,

or use DateTimes and Subtract

At opening

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;//first variable
```

at closing

```
var endTime = Datetime.Now;//second variable
var elapsedSeconds = endtime.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds;//third variable
```